# Сортировка массива по ключу php

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, foreach

Ребят, всем привет. Интересует следующий вопрос.
Есть массив:

```
`$array = [
  'title' => ['Libertines', 'root/rock/index.php', 1],  
  'title1' => ['Britnie', 'root/pop/index.php', 3],
  'title2' => ['Marley', 'root/reaggie/index.php', 4],
  'title4' => ['Wu-tang', 'root/rap/index.php', 2],
];'
```

И функция, которая выводит его как ссылки

```
function menu ($array) { 
 foreach ($array as $titles) { 
    echo '<a href="'.$k[1].'">'.$k[0].'</a>' . " ";};
};
```

Я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы он сортировался по тому порядку, которые указаны в массиве, в качестве 3-го элемента, т.е. должно выглядеть: Libertines, Britnie, Marley, Wu-tang. Подскажите, пожалуйста с решением?

Comment: Массив выводится в том порядке, в котором написан

Comment: А вот откуда берется переменная $k - загадка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Погуглил, если правильно вас понял, то это должно подойти

```
$array = [
    'title' => ['Libertines', 'root/rock/index.php', 1],  
    'title1' => ['Britnie', 'root/pop/index.php', 3],
    'title2' => ['Marley', 'root/reaggie/index.php', 4],
    'title4' => ['Wu-tang', 'root/rap/index.php', 2],
];

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, cmp);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: `return $a[2] <=> $b[2];`

Comment: либо обычное `return $a[2]  - $b[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка массива

```
uasort($array, function($a,$b){return ($a[2]-$b[2]);});
```